# Language fallback working on CM but not on CD

Tags: multilingual, language-fallback

I've enable Language Fallback and everything works as expected on CM, but things are not working out on CD.

1. I've checked the config to be the same on both CM and CD (/App_Config/Sitecore/CMS.Core/Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config)
2. Languages in Sitecore have the fallback language setup and (re)published.

Other settings I didn't do. Am I missing something?

Comment: Worth double checking whether your web db indeed has the published changes as expected.

Comment: You might have missed publishing templates, items... that need the fallback enabled flag on. Try publishing everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure four settings:

- Enable site-level language fallback
- Specify the language fallback rules
- Enable item level fallback
- Enable field level fallback

Sounds like you have configured the first two settings (please ensure you are looking at the correct version of Sitecore too)

Please ensure you [review this full list here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/en/enable-and-set-up-language-fallback.html)

Comment: I deployed a patch which enables site-level language fallback and that was it.

Comment: Great to know this worked, cheers!

Comment: Thank you. Cheers.